# Correct way to add commands to to rc.local above "exit 0" with puppet?

Tags: puppet

A puppet novice, I'm currently working on a deployment script that will start a couple of  [foreverjs](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) services from `rc.local` at boot time.

My concern is that, in Ubuntu, `rc.local` comes with an `exit 0` at the bottom of the file.

I don't [see a way](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib/blob/master/lib/puppet/type/file_line.rb) of using stdlib's `file_line` directive to ensure that my lines appear *above* the exit command (or anywhere else in particular, should the need arise).

I can do it with an `exec` block and some ugly sed, but there must be a more standard, elegant way in puppet?

Comment: Just distribute the whole file or use a template.

Comment: Do you really need to deploy to rc.local?  Can't you build your own init script?

Comment: @yoonix Indeed, my first thought was to just source the whole file, but I don't want to be destructive and overwrite content that might already be there (for whatever reason). The deployment environment is still, shall we say, fluid, so I'd like to leave as much wiggle room as possible.

Comment: @Zoredache Sorry, over-zealous editing: I accidentally deleted the line in my question where I explained that upstart won't work for this (for various silly reasons I am not in a position to fix).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [PuppetLabs Concat module](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-concat) to dynamically insert parts into the `rc.local` file, like so:

Define the file as a concat file, and add a header (hash-bang, "managed by Puppet" comment, etc) - note the below may not work, I'm unsure of Puppet's newline handling off the top of my head!

```
concat { '/etc/rc.local':
  ensure => present,
}

concat::fragment { '00_rc.local_header':
  target  => '/etc/rc.local'
  content => '#!/bin/bash\n# This file is manageed by Puppet, do not modify!',
  order   => '01'
}
```

Add your custom parts, making sure to specify the correct `target` and an `order` value that is higher than your header:

```
concat::fragment { '05_rc.local_custom':
  target  => '/etc/rc.local',
  content => template('path/to/template.erb'),
  order   => '05'
}

concat::fragment { '15_rc.local_custom_2':
  target  => '/etc/rc.local',
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/mymodule/myfile.txt',
  order   => '06'
}
```

Add the `exit 0` footer:

```
concat::fragment { '99_rc.local_footer':
  target  => '/etc/rc.local',
  content => 'exit 0\n',
  order   => '99'
}
```

Et fin!

You can use `concat::fragment` across multiple subclasses (and also multiple modules, though this *really* isn't recommended!) as long as you set the correct `target` value and you have that file declared as a `concat` resource. The `order` parameter allows you to position elements within the file.

Check the [module's usage readme](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-concat#usage) for more.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the cron service installed you can use it for this purpose by using the @reboot time specification. What makes this easier to manage with puppet is that you can just create a separate file in /etc/cron.d instead of trying to edit a single monolithic file.

I tested that the following works:

```
file { "/etc/cron.d/at_startup_myscript":
    content => "@reboot root /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh \n",
}
```